# AI Text Retrieval

Tags: email, google-apps-script, artificial-intelligence, crf++

The aim of my project is to snoop the incoming e-mail messages for meetings, appointments, time intervals, etc. Once, I have the specific content, I would like to update the user's calender.

Now the basic task of retrieving messages, and updating the calender can be done using Google Apps Script.

My query : Because CRF libraries are only available in C++, Java and not JavaScript. Hence, I need to access these messages offline. How do I do that?

PS: Any suggestions about how to go forward with this idea would be appreciated.

Comment: So basically you want to create some text processing to make the AI recognize what kind of e-mail have come to the inbox?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have a **classfication problem** and an **information retrieval problem**. ¹

At first you want to find out, if an incoming mail is either meeting/appointment or something else (two categories). This can be done with so called **Naive Bayes filtering**. This is a probabilistic approach for categorizing mail. It essentially takes a set of *features* and calculates the probability for this mail being both *meeting* and *different*. The theory behind it is based on Bayes rule (probabilistics theory), hence the name.

The second step is then to find the time within the mail. This will be a task for **text-mining**, which unfortunately I am not very good in, yet. Thus I cannot tell you the best method, but a very simplistic approach would be:

Given you already know that this mail is a meeting mail, there should be a timestamp within it. So use a regular expression for timestamps and scan the mail. Take the first timestamp and add it to the calendar. Unfortunately, this will probably lead to quite some errors.

I hope I was able to give you a small overview over the field you are adressing here. I can add more about Bayes (e.g. calculation), if you are interested. Just drop a comment in case.

¹ I am not sure if it really is that and you have not answered the comment. It's also possible, you need some method for downloading already classified mails...